# how to install xgboost on my anaconda running python3.5

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

I'm trying to install xgboost on my anaconda (python3.5, mac OSX).

```
conda install -c aterrel xgboost=0.4.0
```

It looks like xgboost package does not support python3.5??

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.5*
  - xgboost 0.4.0*
```

Really appreciate it if anyone can help with that. How can I install the package with conda install?

Comment: Use this one instead - `conda install -c creditx xgboost=0.62`

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar   I just tried and it did not work.  I  got following message: PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - xgboost 0.62*

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge py-xgboost . It worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the step by step on the official site:

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

xgboost build can be somewhat tricky on windows but it is pretty straight forward on mac.

i would advice for you to first uninstall the prior version you have installed that isnt working.

i would also advice for you to get the most recent version. ( 0.62 i believe)